# Wrong files are loading while starting elasticsearch server (installed OpenDistro in it)

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl, openssl, elasticsearch-opendistro

**Describe the bug**
I have installed OpenDistro plugin using the following command and created the following config files manually. I have configured the elasticsearch.yml file with the created pem files.

**Insall OpenDistro Plugin:** sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-plugin install -b com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch:opendistro_security:1.11.0.0

Config files:

1. root-ca.pem
2. admin-key.pem
3. admin.pem
4. node-key.pem
5. node.pem

Configured in elasticsearch.yml,

```
######## Start OpenDistro for Elasticsearch Security Configuration ########
# WARNING: revise all the lines below before you go into production
opendistro_security.ssl.transport.pemcert_filepath: node.pem
opendistro_security.ssl.transport.pemkey_filepath: node-key.pem
opendistro_security.ssl.transport.pemtrustedcas_filepath: root-ca.pem
opendistro_security.ssl.transport.enforce_hostname_verification: false

opendistro_security.ssl.http.enabled: true
opendistro_security.ssl.http.pemcert_filepath: node.pem
opendistro_security.ssl.http.pemkey_filepath: node-key.pem
opendistro_security.ssl.http.pemtrustedcas_filepath: root-ca.pem
opendistro_security.allow_unsafe_democertificates: false
opendistro_security.allow_default_init_securityindex: true
opendistro_security.authcz.admin_dn:
  - O=Test,L=Chennai, C=IN

opendistro_security.audit.type: internal_elasticsearch
opendistro_security.enable_snapshot_restore_privilege: true
opendistro_security.check_snapshot_restore_write_privileges: true
opendistro_security.restapi.roles_enabled: ["all_access", "security_rest_api_access"]
opendistro_security.system_indices.enabled: true
opendistro_security.system_indices.indices: [".opendistro-alerting-config", ".opendistro-alerting-alert*"]
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled: false
node.max_local_storage_nodes: 3
######## End OpenDistro for Elasticsearch Security Configuration ########
```

But I got the following error while starting the server,

**Error:**

```
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to load plugin class [com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch.security.OpenDistroSecurityPlugin]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:174) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:161) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:127) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:126) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to load plugin class [com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch.security.OpenDistroSecurityPlugin]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:700) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundle(PluginsService.java:642) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:473) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:165) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:328) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:277) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:393) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:691) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundle(PluginsService.java:642) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:473) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:165) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:328) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:277) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:393) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    ... 6 more
**Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Unable to read /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/esnode.pem (/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/esnode.pem). Please make sure this files exists and is readable regarding to permissions. Property: opendistro_security.ssl.transport.pemcert_filepath**
    at com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch.security.ssl.DefaultOpenDistroSecurityKeyStore.checkPath(DefaultOpenDistroSecurityKeyStore.java:929) ~[?:?]
    at com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch.security.ssl.DefaultOpenDistroSecurityKeyStore.resolve(DefaultOpenDistroSecurityKeyStore.java:226) ~[?:?]
    at com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch.security.ssl.DefaultOpenDistroSecurityKeyStore.initTransportSSLConfig(DefaultOpenDistroSecurityKeyStore.java:350) ~[?:?]
    at com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch.security.ssl.DefaultOpenDistroSecurityKeyStore.initSSLConfig(DefaultOpenDistroSecurityKeyStore.java:247) ~[?:?]
    at com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch.security.ssl.DefaultOpenDistroSecurityKeyStore.<init>(DefaultOpenDistroSecurityKeyStore.java:168) ~[?:?]
    at com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch.security.ssl.OpenDistroSecuritySSLPlugin.<init>(OpenDistroSecuritySSLPlugin.java:210) ~[?:?]
    at com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch.security.OpenDistroSecurityPlugin.<init>(OpenDistroSecurityPlugin.java:244) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:691) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundle(PluginsService.java:642) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:473) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:165) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:328) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:277) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:227) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:393) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.1.jar:7.9.1]
    ... 6 more
uncaught exception in thread [main]
```

Why it's expecting esnode.pem instead of using node.pem?

Kindly provide your thoughts on this

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the free security that is included in the default distribution, as this approach isn't supported by Elasticsearch